# Nibble_Swap or Swapping 0x1234

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

The Input is 0x1234 and I want the output as 0x2143 but I am getting 0x4321

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(num) (((num) & 0x0F) << 4) | (((num) & 0xF0) >> 4)

int main() {
    short input = 0x1234;
    short output = SWAP(input);
    
    print("Input: 0x%04X\n", input);
    print("Output: 0x%04X\n", output);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0xF` is just one hex digit. What you're showing in the example at the top is swapping the two bytes of a word, not the two nibbles of a byte.

Comment: As @500-InternalServerError said, your code only swaps nibbles, not bytes. It does that perfectly. Also, there is no way that your code can produce 0x4321 (with any input), as you're only using 8 bits of your input.  Putting in 0x1234 will produce 0x0043.

Comment: As noted above, code doesn't produce the result you say. In fact, it doesn't even compile because it contains errors. [Edit] your question, and post your actual code that compiles and produces the result you say it does.

Answer (score 2):

This macro

```
#define SWAP(num) (((num) & 0x0F) << 4) | (((num) & 0xF0) >> 4)
```

swaps only two nibbles of the less significant byte.

So the result will be

```
0x43
```

If you want to get the output

```
0x2143
```

you need to write

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(num) ( ( ( num ) & 0xF000u ) >> 4 | ( ( num ) & 0x0F00u ) << 4 |\
( ( num ) & 0xF0u ) >> 4 | ( ( num ) & 0x0Fu ) << 4 )

int main( void )
{
    short input = 0x1234;
    short output = SWAP( input );

    printf( "%#x\n", output );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting 0x4321, but 0x0043. You forgot about the higher byte and you wrote `print` instead of `printf`. Code below does what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SWAP(num) (((num) & 0x0F00) << 4) | (((num) & 0xF000) >> 4) | \
    (((num) & 0x0F) << 4) | (((num) & 0xF0) >> 4)

int main() {
    short input = 0x1234;
    short output = SWAP(input);
    
    printf("Input: 0x%04X\n", input);
    printf("Output: 0x%04X\n", output);
    
    return 0;
}
```